# Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session on Appium with Cucumber and Page Objects model

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, pageobjects

I cannot make my code to work...I am using Appium with TestNG and Cucumber

This is my Base.java

```
public class Base {
    public AndroidDriver driver;
   }
```

This is my Hooks.java

```
public class Hooks extends Base{

    private Base base;
    public Hooks (Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Before("@homeScreenTest")
    public void init() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("no",true);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
        cap.setCapability("noRest", true);
        cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
        cap.setCapability("appPackage","myPackage");
        cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "myActivity");

        File f = new File("src");
        File fs = new File(f, "app");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
        base.driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        base.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

This is my Page Object class LanguageSelect.java

```
public class LanguageSelect extends Base{

    public Base base;

    public LanguageSelect (Base base) {
       super();
       this.base= base;
       PageFactory.initElements(base.driver,this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='SET LANGUAGE']")
    public WebElement setLanguage;
}
```

And finally this is my step definition file LandingScreenTest.java

```
public class LandingScreenTest extends Base{

    private Base base;
    public LandingScreenTest(Base base){
        this.base = base;
    }
@Then("^I click on button $")
        public void i_click_on_something(String strArg1) throws Throwable {

        LanguageSelect ls = new LanguageSelect(base);
        ls.setLanguage.click();
        }
}
```

Now the button does not click at all, it is there, it is visible and if I write this in LandingScreenTest.java, it works

```
WebElement setLng = base.driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='SET LANGUAGE']");
        setLng.click();
```

But if I try with page objects I get

```
"org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session"
```

Some times not even a driver is not initialized. I've dug through whole stackoverflow and tons of tutorials but I just cannot get it right.

The reason I keep code in Base.java separated from code in Hooks.java is because Cucumber does not allow me to extend classes with annotations.

What am I missing? Please help

Note: I did not posted runner class nor feature file, everything works except when I try to get objects from page object class.

Comment: I think you're confused as to how extends works.  When a class extends another class, it's like you've imported it, its members become part of the class being extended.  You don't need to, and should not, declare the base class as another class inside the extended class.

Comment: if I don't then I get "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: I thought the NPE was the original problem?  And yet it appears that your solution below is what I suggested?  Regardless, glad you have it working now.

Comment: The original problem was that I could not call anything from page object class, it like it wasn't there. But yeah your suggestion helped a lot. Thanks very much! <3

Answer (score -1):

I have managed it to work. So basically in LanguageSelect class instead of

```
public class LanguageSelect extends Base{

    public Base base;

    public LanguageSelect (Base base) {
       super();
       this.base= base;
       PageFactory.initElements(base.driver,this);
    }
```

I wrote this

```
public class LanguageSelect extends Base{

    public LanguageSelect (AndroidDriver driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
       PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver),this);
    }
```

And it works perfectly fine, everything else in other classes is exactly the same